# what does the "@" sign means in the end of date format in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, date-format, semantics, vba

what does the "@" sign means in the end of date format in Excel VBA ?

```
Columns("U:U").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;@"
Columns("V:V").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;@"
```

does it do anything?

what is the difference if I had wrote .NumberFormat without it?

```
Columns("U:U").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;
Columns("V:V").NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss;
```

my other columns formats are writen without that sign in the end:

```
Columns("K:K").NumberFormat = "#,##0"        
Columns("L:L").NumberFormat = "General"
Columns("M:M").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
Columns("N:N").NumberFormat = "General"
Columns("O:O").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's a custom text -a date followed by time-, the "@" means text.
If you don't set it this happens
[image]
How Excel interface would know what are you trying to do from VBA?

Comment: thank U.
can U please explain me why this "@" sign is only at the end of the date?
I can see it's something different, than "text inside quotation"
please explain this in 2 or 3 sentences.

Comment: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss ---> What. @ --> as what. In this case would be like "date and time" as "custom text", something like it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it. Michal obviously also struggled with the explanation.

Comment: @Tschenser I'm sorry, where is that you are lost?

Comment: After re-reading I think i get your answer. The "@" marks the value as text? Is that it?

Comment: @Tschenser Yes, "@" means as text. Another example where this is clear is where numbers with leading 0's are kept if specfied like so